# How to give a certain Keyboard command to lets say 10-20 tabs Tabs ,

Tags: java, selenium, input, keyboard

How can I spam the keyboard letter input "D" on lets say 10-20 Mozilla windows?

More in detail is this:

I am looking to send the command to these windows as there is an Adobe flash player game running and I am trying to test something by giving a constant input of the keyboard letter "D" on them.

Is there a way to do this in Java Selenium to simultaneously send commands to each one of the mozilla tabs so the command D is constant.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [ask], and [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

```
public void d() throws AWTException {
    Robot rob = new Robot();
    rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
}
```

...

```
int max = 20;
for (int loop = 0; loop <= max; loop++) {d();}
```